# How to get this image to display in the body of my email?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this code, which is supposed to attach a HTML file to the email, and also display the contents of the HTML file in the body of the email.  There is an image (reading.png) referenced in the HTML file that get's displayed every-other line.   However, it is NOT being displayed in the body of the email.  What do I have to do to get it to display?

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])  {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;  //  set delegate to notify us what's happen'in

    [mailer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Site Readings for: %@", gSiteID.globalSiteID]];

    //  add the image for the HTML
    UIImage *toolImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reading.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(toolImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"reading.png"]; 

    // attach file
    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Surveyor" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSData *surveyorTxt= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: file];
    [mailer addAttachmentData: surveyorTxt mimeType:@"text/html" fileName: @"Surveyor.txt"];

    //  display the file in the body of the email
    NSString *reportBody;
    reportBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:databuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [mailer setMessageBody: reportBody isHTML:true];  //  indicate the body is html

    [self presentModalViewController: mailer animated:TRUE];
```

This is the HTML which is to be displayed:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='default.css'/>
</head>
 <body>
 STA:&nbsp;TBM "J" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Elev:&nbsp;19.76<br>Desc:&nbsp;USGS Test Site
 <div>
 <table border class="boldtable">
 <tr BGCOLOR="ADDAFE">
 <th>STA&nbsp;</th>
 <th>BS&nbsp;</th>
 <th>HI&nbsp;</th>
 <th>FS&nbsp;</th>
 <th>ELEV&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Desc</th>
 </tr>
 <p><tr>
 <td> TBM "J"</td>
 <td></td><td></td><td></td>
 <td>19.76</td>
 <td>USGS Test Site</td>
 <p><tr
 ><td><img src="reading.png" align=center></td><td>3.14</td><td valign="middle">22.90</td>
```

UPDATE:  I don't think I was clear enough... In the HTML which is displayed in the outgoing message, there should be an image that appears throughout the HTML.  I have no problem attaching the image to the message, but it does NOT appear in the HTML, which is where I want it.  So clearly attaching the image to the message is not working... (I thought it would).

HTH...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the base 64 answer. Here was my solution using a common NSData base 64 category.

```
static NSString *EmailBody(NSString *description, UIImage *image)
{
    NSString *format = @"<html>"
    @"<body>"
    @"<p>%@</p>"
    @"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></b></p>"
    @"</body>"
    @"</html>";
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);    
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:format, description, [imageData base64EncodedString]];
}
```

---

Just to clarify things, I'll use your example.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='default.css'/>
</head>
 <body>
 STA:&nbsp;TBM "J" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Elev:&nbsp;19.76<br>Desc:&nbsp;USGS Test Site
 <div>
 <table border class="boldtable">
 <tr BGCOLOR="ADDAFE">
 <th>STA&nbsp;</th>
 <th>BS&nbsp;</th>
 <th>HI&nbsp;</th>
 <th>FS&nbsp;</th>
 <th>ELEV&nbsp;</th>
 <th>Desc</th>
 </tr>
 <p><tr>
 <td> TBM "J"</td>
 <td></td><td></td><td></td>
 <td>19.76</td>
 <td>USGS Test Site</td>
 <p><tr
 ><td><img src="data:image/png;base64,##########" align=center></td><td>3.14</td><td valign="middle">22.90</td>
```

Where ########## is replaced with the data of reading.png after it's been base 64 encoded.

Comment: So what am I doing here?  Why do I need all of the HTML?  All I want to do is get the image to appear in the attached HTML...

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing. You only need `<img src='data:image/png;base64,**BASE64 ENCODED DATA**'>` in your HTML. My example was a complete HTML email message with a description of the image above the image.

Comment: Hi Jeffery... thanks for checking back... so, let me make sure I understand this:  I can do something like this: "NSString encStr = [imageData base64EncodedString];", then replace the ####### above in your code with "encStr"? (src="data:image/png;base64,encStr"...)

Comment: Yes, using something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"... <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,%@\" align=center> ...", [imageData base64EncodedString]]`. NOTE: base64EncodedString is not a method provided by Apple. You have to find a category that will add on base 64 encoding. I got mine from [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html). At the very bottom of the article is a link to a zip file. The zip file has NSData+Base64.h and NSData+Base64.m files that you need.

Comment: This approach no longer produces embedded images that can be viewed in gmail. Instead, the raw data stream is shown.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use the data encoded in base64:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" align=center alt="reading">
```

Answer (score 3):

For an image load in an email, the image tag has to have a full url in it, and the image should be located on a server somewhere so that it can be loaded:

`<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/reading.png" align=center>`

Comment: And well-behaving email programs will refuse to load that.

Comment: Indeed in order to display image in email, the src property should contain well formed url

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter in an NSString stringWithFormat, and insert the .png into the NSString. I tried your code in Xcode 3, did my instuctions, and it worked. Hope it helps!